# unorderable types: str() > int() python

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
import sys

def main():
   a = bool(sys.argv[1])
   b = str(sys.argv[2])
   c = float(sys.argv[3])
   d = int(sys.argv[4])
   for x in sys.argv:
      print(x)
   if a == True and b > d:
      print(c+d)
   else:
      b_upper = b.upper()
      print(b_upper)




main()
```

Im getting this error:

```
File "commline.py", line 19, in <module>
   main()
File "commline.py", line 10, in main
   if a == True and b > d:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Im trying to get the program to do this:

- if the Boolean value is True and the length of the string is greater than the integer value, print the sum of the float and the integer
- otherwise, print the string converted to uppercase

Here is an example of what the output should look like:

```
python3 commline.py True "Peter Pan" 3.14159 7
True
Peter Pan
3.14159
7
Result:
10.14159
```

Comment: Use `len()` to get the length of the string: `len(b) > d`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `len()`:

```
if a == True and len(b) > d:
```

Comment: don't test :

`if a == True:`

it's enough to do `if a:`